# NFA-lambda to DFA conversion

Tags: dfa, nfa

Can somebody help me to convert this nfa-lambda to dfa?

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is for practical programming questions. Abstract computer science questions should be posted to [cs.se] or [math.se] instead.

Comment: What do you mean by lambda/landa? I'm used to seeing epsilon (ε) for empty transitions, not lambda (λ).

Comment: The lines on the top and bottom of the circled section are missing arrowheads. I presume those are supposed to be backwards transitions. (Why are there two? They're the same thing, right?)

Answer (score 0):

I have created one DFA like below.

[image]

where q3 and q4 is accepted state and q0 is starting state.